# Sorting PHP Array by Integer Values while keeping Key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this

```
[Title 1] => 2
[Title 2] => 4
[Title 3] => 3
[Title 4] => 1
```

All I'm trying to do is sort the integer value in the array, to get an output like this:

```
[Title 2] => 4
[Title 3] => 3
[Title 1] => 2
[Title 4] => 1
```

I don't think it matters, but my array is created by the [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function.

```
$array = array_count_values($originalarray);
```

I've looked through the manual on [PHP: Array Sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) but can't get anything to work.

I've tried a few things that look like they *might* work.

```
$newarray = arsort($array);
```

This just outputs `1`

same with `rsort`.

The closest I've come is by using [array_multisort](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) by using it as such:

```
$array = array_count_values($originalarray);
$newarray = array_multisort($array, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
```

Now if I do a `print_r($array)` it outputs like this:

```
[Title 2] => 4
[1] => 3
[Title 1] => 2
[2] => 1
```

Meaning it's, for some reason, and seemingly randomly, destroying the key value in the array and putting in place `1`, `2`, etc in place of `Title #`

This seems like it would be so easy, yet I've been trying multiple things without luck. Can anyone shine some light on this for me?

Comment: `arsort($array)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Comment: Tried that. Read the full question for all the things I've tried. `arsort` is just outputting `1`

Comment: @BrianBruman change `$newarray = arsort($array);` to just `arsort($array);` then inspect `$array` this function acts by reference.

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` functions in php return `boolean` not an array - http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php
`Sort` function will update the array you put as parameter
Should be like this

```
<?php
$array = [];
arsort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Doh! That was the first thing I tried like two hours ago haha.  But I was trying to put it in a variable.  Knew it should've been easy.  This works.